# How to make some Products visible to a single Customer Group?

Tags: magento2.3, customer-group

I  know this has been asked before but could not get a reliable answer without suggesting some paid extension.

I need to hide some products to be visible only to user with some group id.
I have a boolean attribute set to products called `is_secure`. I want products with this attribute set to true to be only visible to customers with group id = 2.

How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be solved without a complete extension. 
This is because hiding a product means hiding in many different places including search, catalog, direct link to the product and so on.

So I needed to create an extension and write plugins to each of these areas and remove the products from product collections there using plugins.